# What cells are secreting Wnt pathways and under which conditions?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling, pathway

*Former question: Where and how happen these operations in the Wnt signaling pathway?*

I have read about the signaling pathway on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wnt_signaling_pathway):

> Wnt comprises a diverse family of secreted lipid-modified signaling glycoproteins that are 350–400 amino acids in length.[11] The lipid modification of all Wnts is palmitoleoylation of a single totally conserved serine residue.[12] Palmitoleoylation is necessary because it is required for Wnt to bind to its carrier protein Wntless (WLS) so it can be transported to the plasma membrane for secretion[13] and it allows the Wnt protein to bind its receptor Frizzled [14][15] Wnt proteins also undergo glycosylation, which attaches a carbohydrate in order to ensure proper secretion.[16] In Wnt signaling, these proteins act as ligands to activate the different Wnt pathways via paracrine and autocrine routes

Where happen these chemical reactions described in this quote ?
My understanding is that they happen outside of cells, before the arrival of the Wnt ligand on the receptor that is located at the surface of the cell. Am I correct?
If yes, were does this happen precisely in the body? Where the ligand comes from?

---

**EDIT:**
From comments: The Wnt ligand is secreted by other cells and transmitted from cell to cell, this is an autocrine process.

**The question is: Under which conditions does this process start in one cell?**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146357/discussion-on-question-by-totalmongot-what-cells-are-secreting-wnt-pathways-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.